# MongoDB cursor.limit() times out if not enough documents

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this query in the shell which works exactly like the one I'm trying to get working in java:

```
db.documents.find({a query which works just fine}).max({archiveDate:"2015-04-14T11:24:50.004-0400",_id:ObjectId("553531139bb0d56edc9e4b9c")}).sort({archiveDate:-1,_id:-1}).skip(1).limit(12).maxTimeMS(1000)
```

The java equivalent would be more like this:

```
DBCursor dbCursor = documentCollection.find(query)
                    .max(new BasicDBObject().append("archiveDate", "2015-04-14T11:24:50.004-0400").append("_id", new ObjectId("553531139bb0d56edc9e4b9c"))
                    .sort(new BasicDBObject().append("archiveDate", -1).append("_id", -1)
                    .limit(12)
                    .skip(1)
                    .maxTime(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

(where documentCollection is a DBCollection and query is properly defined and works just fine, but is kind of cumbersome to plug in here).

I'm using `max()`, `sort()`, `limit()`, and `skip()` to get around the usual skip and limit performance issues for large collections.

In any case the document being referenced in the `max()` method is #12 in the sorted collection, so it should be returning exactly 11 documents.  Instead it times out when I try to iterate over the cursor, since I've defined the maximum time it can take to be one second.

If I remove the time constraint it will take about 10 seconds to run.  If I set the limit to 11 then it will run more or less instantly.

So the problem appears to be happening when this query is given a limit which exceeds the number of documents available to be returned.

I don't understand why this happens, so I was hoping:

(a) someone knows and could explain why it's happening, and

(b) how can I get around it?  My Google-fu has revealed nothing.

I won't know when making the query what position the document is in, so I won't know how many documents could be returned, and therefore couldn't tailor the limit value to suit its position.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `max()` (which is usually not quite what people think it is) why not add such filters to your query directly?  A `$max` without a `$min` is [discouraged](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/#max-without-min).

Comment: This isn't the use case.  The query returns whatever it returns; all of this is just for pagination purposes, which is the reason I can't use max() and min() at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've in my mind is get the lower bound using query:

```
db.documents.find({a query which works just fine}).sort({archiveDate:1,_id:1}).limit(1);
```

Once you've this bound you can apply it for the query that's failing. Since we can't say if the page is last page or not, you might either have to query this value every time before making call for next page or persist across requests by either constructing next page link using this value or cache it.
if there is a possibility of changing lower bound while caller is fetching pages, then you don't have a choice but go with first option only. i.e. get lower bound before making a next page request.

Since you've posted this query a while ago and I'm sure you must have figured out a solution. I want to understand how you got around this problem and could you share what the issue is.